# Indentation for quotes in LaTeX

Tags: indentation, quoting

Sometimes when we use a long quote, we want the paragraph for the quote to indent from both the left side and the right side. What is the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Standard LaTeX provides the `quote` (no inner indentation, intended for short quotations) and `quotation` (inner indentation, intended for longer quotations) environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[4]
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I change the indentation for the quote?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using, with the `memoir` document class.

```latex
\renewenvironment{quote}{
  \noindent     % No indent of first character.
  \topsep=0pt   % No additional separator before.
  \parskip=0pt  % No paragraph separator.

  \interlinepenalty=10000  % Prevent a page break to occur in a quote block.
  \leftskip=0pt 
  \rightskip=0pt 
  \parfillskip=0pt 
  \RaggedRight
  \itshape  % Make quotations in italic.
  \list{}{
    \leftmargin 1em   % this is the adjusting screw
    \rightmargin 1em  % this is the adjusting screw
  }
  \item
  \relax
  }
  {\endlist}
```